# Creating custom map to search for function definition in Vim

Tags: php, vim

Suppose I am writing some PHP code and I come up with a function call that I know its defined in this file. I would like to create a mapping so that it automatically looks for `'function <WORD_UNDER_CURSOR>'`.

I managed to do this by using `nmap <Leader>8 /function <C-r><C-w><CR>`, but the problem is that my search wrapping is off (and I want it that way), so half of the time I end up with the reached end of screen error and have to press `N` myself to look upwards. I tried to append an `Nn` to the end of the mapping (`nmap <Leader>8 /function <C-r><C-w><CR>Nn`) but it did not work. I don't know why! In fact anything I put after the `<CR>` does not seem to have any effect.

Could you guys give me suggestions and explain to me? I found that the documentation on Vim mappings are really, REALLY difficult to find what your looking for. For instance, I still don't know what `<C-r><C-w>` is!

Comment: Prepend your mapping with `gg`, that way you search from the beginning of the file. Are you familiar with `#` and `*`, they come pretty close to what you want.

Comment: I would highly recommend you try excellent plugin [Tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/). It works for a variety of file formats and is probably the solution you are really looking for.

Comment: @Thor I had already tried prepending with gg, but then the word under cursor becomes the first word of the file :) .  And yes, i am familiar with * and #, but they dont take me directly to the function definition, on large files (and i am dealing with some REALY large files) this can be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gathered information from all of the answers and comments above and the help files and compiled this answer as no one had answered directly. I have found two solutions:

1-
We could copy `yiw` the word under the cursor, and then `gg` to the top of the file. Finally we search for "`function <C-r>"` which means, function space contents from register " (last yank). Side effects: If nothing is found, you are now on the top of your file, messes up registers. :-/

```
nmap <Leader>8 yiwgg /function <C-r>"<CR>
```

2-
My personal creation, which is a correction of the original command in the question:

```
nmap <Leader>8 /function <C-r><C-w><CR> Nn
```

did not work because the / command was throwing a 'not found error', which aborted the rest of the mapping. So we can either find a way to ignore errors (which I looked for but could not find), or use:

```
:nmap <Leader>8 :call search('function <C-r><C-w>','w')<CR>
```

Notice the 'w' flag, which means wrap around! Look for `:help search`.

---

Extras:

3- The perfect world right_way_to_do_it: 
   Use `gD` if your file is organized or ctags.

For curiosity's sake, I used `<Leader>8` because of the * on top of 8. :)

Answer (score 1):

To search forward you use `/` and to search backward you use `?`. So just use the `?` in your existing map instead of `/`.

`<C-r><C-w>` is emacs notation for `^R^W`. I don't know what emacs notation is doing in a vi implementation, but there it is. `:help ^R^W` works though. It just inserts the word under the cursor.

Comment: You dont understand, i need to search fowards & backwards, because i dont know where the func def may be.  Thks on the ^R^W though, i will have a look on the help (i am not on my beatiful linux right now.)

Comment: In that case I'd use the `gg` idea. You need to yank the word under the cursor first. How about `yawgg/<C-r>"<CR>`

Answer (score 1):

Vim can do that natively with `gd` which means "go to definition", which is by the way not limited to functions. See `:help gd`.

---

The `<C-r><C-w>` notation is used all over the place in Vim's documentation and is more or less the standard way to write a combo when talking about vim. The standard notation for Emacs would be `C-r C-w`, without the `<>`.

Type `:help` for quick hints about using the documentation and `:help key-notation` for further details on keys/combos issues and… key notation.

In your case, `:help ctrl-r_ctrl-w` or `:help <c-r>_<c-w>` (notice the underscore) would have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mapping based on `:grep` that should do what you want (see [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1543) for more):

```
map <buffer> <F3> :grep 'function.*<C-r><C-w>' %<CR><CR>
```